# Dealing with XML errors in RSS feeds using SyndicationFeed.Load

Tags: .net, rss, syndicationfeed

When reading in a 3rd party RSS feed an XMLException is thrown due to an invalid DateTime in the feed XML.

How can I handle this more robustly. For example, is there a way to catch the exception, identify the problematic element and deal with it (e.g. insert a placeholder) and continue the load?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you properly use xmlns namespaces with custom extensions to .NET SyndicationFeeds?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787853/how-do-you-properly-use-xmlns-namespaces-with-custom-extensions-to-net-syndicat)